# Guessing Game (Python) Problems. Total beginner

Tags: python

I have a few days of Python knowledge. I've been going to courses like Codecademy and I wanted to dive into a project. I followed a YouTube video at the start of this project to get the hang of it.

My game will ask if it wants to be played, if "yes" it will keep playing. If "no" the program will stop. I don't know how to change this to make it keep playing.

The program also will not show that the number is greater than or less than after the `while` loop shows up. Originally I had that section of code after the `while` loop, but it made no difference.

I'm just a total beginner who wanted to learn Python better with an actual project, so I really am not sure which steps to take here:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,10)
tries = 1

name = input("Hello, What is your name?")

print("Hello there,", name)

question = input("Time to guess, ready? [Y/N]")
if question == "n":
    print("sorry, lets go!")

if question == "y":
    print("Im thinking of a number between 1 and 10.")
    guess = int(input("Have a guess"))

    if guess < number:
        print("That is too low!")
    if guess == number:
        print("Congrats! You win!!")
    if guess > number:
        print("That is too high!")
while guess != number:
        tries += 1
        guess = int(input("Try again: "))
```

.

```
Hello, What is your name?name
Hello there, name
Time to guess, ready? [Y/N]y
Im thinking of a number between 1 and 10.
Have a guess1
That is too low!
Try again: 10
Try again: 10
Try again: 10
Try again:
```

The message "too high" is never displayed.

Comment: put code in another `while` loop and it will run again after you guess number.

Answer (score 0):

The if statements can go inside the while loop.

And you can use the break statement to terminate the while loop.

You can find more details here: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `elif` not consecutive `if` statements. Change your `while` loop to allow `break`ing out, so you can display the correct win message.

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,10)
tries = 1

name = input("Hello, What is your name?")

print("Hello there,", name)

question = input("Time to guess, ready? [Y/N]")
if question == "n":
    print("sorry, lets go!")

if question == "y":
    print("Im thinking of a number between 1 and 10.")
    guess = int(input("Have a guess"))

while True:
    if guess < number:
        print("That is too low!")
    elif guess == number:
        print("Congrats! You win!!")
        break
    elif guess > number:
        print("That is too high!")
    tries += 1
    guess = int(input("Try again: "))
```

Comment: How would I go about making it so that if the user says No at the beginning, the game says sorry and makes them guess anyway. Thank you for the if and elif tips

Comment: Then just remove the checks for the `question` variable and continue with the loop...

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @furas in that this really should be a pair of nested `while` loops with a structure something like:

```
import random

name = input("Hello, What is your name? ")

print("Hello there,", name)

answer = "y"

while answer.lower().startswith("y"):
    number = random.randint(1, 10)

    print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10.")
    guess = int(input("Have a guess: "))

    while True:
        if guess < number:
            print("That is too low!")
        elif guess > number:
            print("That is too high!")
        else:
            print("Congrats! You win!")
            break

        guess = int(input("Try again: "))

    answer = input("Play again? [Y/N]: ")

print("Goodbye!")
```